# ASP.NET MVC AJAX Open PDF with parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, pdf, pdfsharp

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I built a controller returning a PDF file.
I build the PDF with PDFsharp:

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(string Param)
{ 
    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

    // Create an empty page
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    // Create a font
    XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

    // Draw the text
    gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
    new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
    XStringFormats.Center);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Save(stream, false);
    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

    return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Now my goal is to send an AJAX request from jQuery and open the PDF file in a new tab. Besides that I want to pass a parameter to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, opening file directly through ajax is not easy.

So I would suggest another route.

When jquery send ajax to get pdf generated, instead of returning the File, return a **link to the file**, in which you can open that link
like url in a new tab.

So first change your action to return a link:

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(string Param)
{
  // same as before
  ....

  // save your pdf to a file
  File.WriteAllBytes("result.pdf", memoryStream.ToArray());

  // get url to that pdf which can be browsed
  var pdfUrl = "some location which url can browse";

  return Json(new {url = pdfUrl}, JsonBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

then in the view where you jquery ajax fired, when get the result back, just browse to that pdf url

```
$.getJSON( "your GenerateReport url", function( data ) {
    window.open(data.url,'_blank');
}
```

Comment: There is a mistake in C# code. Should be `new {url = pdfUrl}` instead of `new {url: pdfUrl}`

Comment: @dremerDT nice catch and thanks for the feedback.
I have modified the answer